# Can you cast Minor Illusion without being noticed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

The spell has a somatic and material component, can it be cast without someone knowing you are casting a spell?

Comment: Related: [How loud/obvious is a wizard casting a spell?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/a/141041)

Comment: I think you should edit your question to indicate how it is different from the one I linked above. As you have it written now this question seems either like a duplicate or like something asking for a potentially unbound list of ways to do this.